# Can someone help me with converting the workflow rule criteria into SOQL query?

Tags: soql

I am trying to convert the following workflow rule criteria into a SOQL query?

```
NOT(ISBLANK(WhoId)) &&
CONTAINS(Queue_Name__c, 'Sales_General') &&
NOT(ISBLANK(CallDisposition )) &&
TEXT(Country__c) = 'Canada' &&
(
    (CONTAINS(CallDisposition, 'Account')) &&
    (
        NOT(CONTAINS(CallDisposition, 'Transfer')) ||
        (CONTAINS(CallDisposition, 'Order')) || 
        (CONTAINS(CallDisposition, 'Insurance')) || 
        (CONTAINS(CallDisposition, 'Opportunity')) || 
        (CONTAINS(CallDisposition, 'Pharmacy')) || 
        (CONTAINS(CallDisposition, 'Product')) || 
        (CONTAINS(CallDisposition, 'Return'))
    )
)
```

I have framed this SOQL query from the workflow rule

```
select id, WhoId, Queue_Name__c, CallDisposition, Preferred_Language__c, Country__c, RecordType.name, createddate from task where whoid <> null and Queue_Name__c like '%Sales_General%' and CallDisposition <> null and Country__c = 'Canada' and (CallDisposition like '%Account%' and (not CallDisposition like '%Transfer%') or CallDisposition like '%Order%' or CallDisposition like '%Insurance%' or CallDisposition like '%Opportunity%' or CallDisposition like '%Pharmacy%' or CallDisposition like '%Product%' or CallDisposition like '%Return%') and CreatedDate = LAST_N_DAYS:2 and RecordType.name like 'CA%' order by createddate
```

I am getting the following error message on running the query

> MALFORMED_QUERY:
> CallDisposition like '%Transfer%') or CallDisposition like '%Order%'
> ^
> ERROR at Row:1:Column:321
> expecting a right parentheses, found 'or'

Can someone please help me fix the SOQL so that it can run successfully?

Answer (score 4):

SOQL doesn't like it when you try to mix `AND` and `OR`. The order that they're evaluated in can make a difference in which records are returned, so Salesforce forces us to explicitly define how to group.

This is *kinda* documented at the bottom of [the page on the WHERE clause](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_conditionexpression.htm)

> You can use parentheses to define the order in which fieldExpressions are evaluated. You must specify parentheses when nesting operators. However, multiple operators of the same type do not need to be nested.

Like the error message is pointing you towards, the issue is

```java
...
Country__c = 'Canada' 
and (
    CallDisposition like '%Account%' and 
    (not CallDisposition like '%Transfer%') or
...
```

That's where you're mixing `AND` and `OR`. You could fix this by wrapping all of the conditions you're `OR`ing in a single set of parenthesis (following what's in the workflow formula)

So your query should look something like

```java
SELECT
    Id, WhoId, Queue_Name__c, CallDisposition, Preferred_Language__c, Country__c, 
    RecordType.name, Createddate 
FROM 
    Task 
WHERE 
    WhoId <> null 
    AND Queue_Name__c LIKE '%Sales_General%' 
    AND CallDisposition <> null 
    AND Country__c = 'Canada' 
    AND ( 
        CallDisposition LIKE '%Account%'
        //  v Extra set of parenthesis that mirrors your formula
        AND (
            (NOT CallDisposition LIKE '%Transfer%')
            OR CallDisposition LIKE '%Order%'
            OR CallDisposition LIKE '%Insurance%'
            OR CallDisposition LIKE '%Opportunity%'
            OR CallDisposition LIKE '%Pharmacy%'
            OR CallDisposition LIKE '%Product%'
            OR CallDisposition LIKE '%Return%'
        )
    ) 
    AND CreatedDate = LAST_N_DAYS:2 
    AND RecordType.name LIKE 'CA%' 
ORDER BY
    createddate
```

All of the `OR`s are contained together within those parenthesis, so there is no more mixing of AND/OR/NOT (except for the NOT LIKE, which needs to be wrapped in its own pair of parenthesis as you have already done).

There is a *little* simplification that can be done (`CallDisposition LIKE '%Account%'` could be pulled out one level higher), but it may make sense to just leave things as they are. The more important thing here is grouping things together in a way that helps you read/visualize what's going on.

The other thing here is to recognize the importance of how you format things like formulas and WHERE clauses. Putting things on separate lines and indenting an extra level each time you encounter an open paren makes it *much easier* to see the logical structure/grouping of conditions.

Aside from my choice of putting `AND`/`OR` at the beginning, it should look like this was a 1:1 translation from your formula into SOQL

Comment: Hi Derek F, Thanks for your reply if you could help me further I am trying to convert this workflow rule conditions into a SOQL

Comment: NOT(ISBLANK(WhoId)) &&
 CONTAINS(Queue_Name__c, 'Sales_General') &&
 NOT(ISBLANK(CallDisposition )) &&
 TEXT(Country__c) = 'Canada' &&
 ((CONTAINS(CallDisposition, 'Account')) &&
(NOT(CONTAINS( CallDisposition, 'Transfer') ) || (CONTAINS(CallDisposition, 'Order')) || (CONTAINS(CallDisposition, 'Insurance')) || (CONTAINS(CallDisposition, 'Opportunity')) || (CONTAINS(CallDisposition, 'Pharmacy')) || (CONTAINS(CallDisposition, 'Product'))|| (CONTAINS(CallDisposition, 'Return'))))

Comment: Sorry, I am new to Salesforce Stack Exchange. Should I edit the question, will that help?

Comment: I have edited the question. Let me know if that works.

Comment: @SalomePalani Done with edits to my answer, and I've deleted my other comments (since they served their purpose)

Comment: Hi @derek, Thanks a lot for helping me out with the SOQL and the explanation. I appreciate your help.